# How to write relational algebra for SQL WHERE column IN?

Tags: sql, join, relational-algebra, sql-in

```
select age from person where name in (select name from eats where pizza="mushroom")
```

I am not sure what to write for the "in". How should I solve this?

Comment: Double quotes are for (delimited) identifiers. Do you have a column called mushroom? (Use single quotes for string literals.)

Comment: select age from person where name in (select name from eats where pizza='mushroom')

Comment: go and first check what relational algebra is!!!

Comment: Please give a reference to what "relational algebra" you are to use.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the sub-select is equivalent to a join:

```
select age 
from person p, eats e
where p.name = e.name and pizza='mushroom'
```

So you could translate it in:

π<sub>age</sub> (person p ⋈<sub>p.name=e.name</sub> (σ<sub>pizza='mushroom'</sub>(eats e)))

Comment: Do I have to change it to its equivalent? Can't I do same for the above without being changed?

Comment: Certainly. I showed the equivalent SQL Query just for clarity, but you can translate directly your query in the algebra expression.

Comment: @BabuaPantu There is no operator IN in any classical version of the relational algebra.

Comment: @philipxy,  is Marcin Wroblewski's answer above correct as they used belong operator which I never heard is used in relational algebra.

Comment: @BabuaPantu As I already commented on your question, *you* have to tell *us* what *you* mean by "relational algebra". If you don't know what you mean, find out from the person who gave you your assignment. (Although if you don't know what a word means, why are you using it?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess. I'm assuming that [set membership symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_(mathematics)) is part of relational algebra

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For base table r, C a column of both r & s, and x an unused name,

```
select ... from r where C in s
```

returns the same value as

```
select ... from r natural join (s) x
```

The use of `in` requires that s has one column. The `in` is true for a row of r exactly when its C equals the value in s. So the `where` keeps exactly the rows of r whose C equals the value in s. We assumed that s has column C, so the `where` keeps exactly the rows of r whose C equals the C of the row in r. Those are same rows that are returned by the `natural join`.

(For an expression like this `where`-`in` with C not a column of both r and s then this translation is not applicable. Similarly, the reverse translation is only applicable under certain conditions.)

How useful this particular translation is to you or whether you could simplify it or must complexify it depends on what variants of SQL & "relational algebra" you are using, what limitations you have on input expressions and other translation decisions you have made. If you use very straightforward and general translations then the output is more complex but obviously correct. If you translate using a lot of special case rules and ad hoc simplifications along the way then the output is simpler but the justification that the answer is correct is longer.